# Format number with 3 decimals in Access query, like 1000,000. 3 digits after comma

Tags: sql, ms-access, rounding

Example : SELECT  SUM(transf2.amt) as b1

I tried Format(SUM(transf2.amt),3) also Round doesn't work.

```
SQ = " SELECT  SUM(transf2.amt) as b1     "
SQ = SQ & " FROM        transf1 INNER JOIN "
SQ = SQ & "  transf2 ON transf1.Trans_Num = transf2.Trans_Num "
SQ = SQ & " where   (transf1.[Date] <= #" & Format(Trim(period(0)), "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#) and   transf2.acc=" & AccNo
SQ = SQ & " and transf1.cur_no=" & Val(account_no(6))
```

Comment: Very rusty on access, but `Format(SUM(transf2.amt), "0.000")` maybe?

Comment: I've Tried This Way But There Were An Compile Error Caused By The Double Quotation's

Comment: Use apostrophes in place of the quote marks. That format utilizes a period, not a comma. What language is your db set for? What are your computer regional settings? Why do you need to format in query? Why not in textbox on report?

Comment: The language that was coordinated with DB is VB6, and the regional settings of the device do not have any defects. What I want is to make Sum for a field, and this field is a grouping. In the local currency compared to the foreign currency, and the problem I have is that the collection process collects approximately 7 digits after the comma. I just want to force it to calculate by 3 digits after the comma, keep on ur mind that I have a SUM Function
Thank you

Comment: Format and FormatNumber both return a string, not a number, and that will cause issue with subsequent calculations. Will have to convert back to a number.  By language I meant English or what, not programming language. Examples suggested use a period, yet you keep saying "digits after comma". Example in your title shows a comma so is that a decimal comma? Again, what language/currency?

Comment: Do you want to round the individual data or the Sum result?

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
SQ = "SELECT FormatNumber(SUM(transf2.amt), 3) as b1 "
```

For basic rounding of the individual values:

```
SQ = "SELECT SUM(Round(transf2.amt, 3)) as b1 "
```

For basic rounding of the sum:

```
SQ = "SELECT Round(SUM(transf2.amt), 3) as b1 "
```

For high-precision rounding, use `RoundMid` found in my library [VBA.Round](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Round).

Comment: didn't worked  still calculating 7 digits After Comma

Comment: Then try with `FormatNumber`.